# how to change property of all text boxes matching particular class using jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, textinput

this is my jquery code. http://jsfiddle.net/geekrule/ZnAvP/1/
as i select an image,a text-box is added with the image's source and a 'name' property is added.
now when i unselect the image,i want the 'name' to be updated.

**for ex:** 
`i select images 1,3,4,5
corresponding value of 'name' of input boxes will be 1,2,3,4
and now when i unselect images -3,4
value of 'name' should be 1 and 2(this part is what i am stuck at.the values i get are 1,4).`

they are not getting updated.
hope you understood the problem.please help me out. thanks in advance

Comment: @forsvarir i made some changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion the simpler solition is to re-generate textboxes on each image selection:

```
<div id="selectList">
    <img src="http://tinyurl.com/26asnv7" />
    <img src="http://tinyurl.com/26asnv7" />
    <img src="http://tinyurl.com/26asnv7" />
    <img src="http://tinyurl.com/26asnv7" />
    <img src="http://tinyurl.com/26asnv7" />
    <img src="http://tinyurl.com/26asnv7" />
    <img src="http://tinyurl.com/26asnv7" />
    <img src="http://tinyurl.com/26asnv7" />
</div><form id='if' name='forms' method='post'>
<button type='submit' class="uploadPic">Upload Fb</button>
</form>
​
$(function() {
    $("#selectList img").click(
    function(event) {
        if( !$(this).is(".clicked") && $("#selectList img.clicked").length >= 3){
            event.preventDefault();
            alert('only 3 photos allowed');
            return;
        }
        $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
        regenerateTextBoxes();
    });
});

function regenerateTextBoxes() {
    $('#if .selection').remove();
    $("#selectList img.clicked").each(function(index, element) {
        var $input = $('<div>', {
            'class': 'selection',
            'html': $('<input>', {
                'type': 'text',
                'value': $(this).attr('src'),
                'name': 'pics' + index
            })
        });

        $("#if").append($input);
    });
}​
```